# Specifying constraints with nloptr using the ISRES search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, constraints, nlopt

I have a nonlinear minimization problem with nonlinear constraints but no jacobian.
I want to use ISRES search algorithm from the `nloptr` R optimization package. I'm a bit confused about whether I should define the inequality constraints as ineq<=0 or ineq>=. In the documentation of nloptr it appears that the inequality constraints should be formulated as ineq<=0, while in the documentation of the ISRES function the inequality constraints are said to be formulated as ineq>=0.

Answer (score 0):

In your optimazation problem (nloptr) you should write:

`eval_g_ineq  = your_inequality`

It will works.

You should define "your inequality" as inequal to zero.

For example if you would like to say x can not be equal to 2 you should formulate it as

```
your_inequality <- (x - 2)
```